Does Datacap have a way to read searchable pdf instead of using OCR?
I'm working with searchable pdf, there is no need to OCR the document.  Is there a rule/action in Datacap that can read the data instead of using OCR?

#OCR #IBM #Datacap

Yes, in IBM Datacap, there is a way to extract data from a searchable PDF without using OCR. This can be done by utilizing the PDF actions that are available in Datacap. Specifically, you can use the PDF action library which provides a set of actions for working with PDF files.
Using PDF Actions in Datacap
Here are some of the key actions from the PDF action library that you can use to extract text from a searchable PDF:
PDF::GetPDFText: This action extracts text from a PDF and places it into a specified variable.
PDF::ExtractText: This action extracts text from specific coordinates or zones within the PDF.

Can you add a reference?  I cannot find these actions.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/datacap/9.1.9?topic=actions-pdf

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rpa/23.0?topic=pdf-get-text-by-ocr

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rpa/23.0?topic=SSTHBP_23.0.x/using_ibm_rpa/ocr/using/using_pdf_text_extractor.htm

Your reference is not Datacap.  Or am I not understanding something?
